# display clickable links from JAVA to HTML href with their URL images/text etc

Tags: javascript, html

have simple calculation that if the selected 2 radio are true it will display the correct link to the href for where you can find it. the link pops up in the HTML but if you click it, it goes to home page

```
enter code here

some of the HTML 
<div class="alignment">
 <label class="container">Stereo        
  <img class="portimg" src="img/av.svg" alt="astereoout">
   <input type="radio" name="Audio1" value="1" id="astereoout">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
 </label>
</div>
<div class="alignment">
 <label class="container">Optical
   <img class="portimg" src="img/Optical.svg" alt="aOpticalin">
     <input type="radio" name="Audio2" value="9" id="aOpticalin">
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
</div>
<button onclick="Selectport()" id="BtnData" 
class="Selectport">Select</button>

<a class="Results" id="DisplayResults" href=""></a>
</html>

javascript
function Selectport() {

var aOpticalin = document.getElementById("aOpticalin");
var aOpticalout = document.getElementById("aOpticalout");
var astereoout = document.getElementById("astereoout");
var astereoin = document.getElementById("astereoin");
var DisplayResults = document.getElementById("DisplayResults");

var OptoAv = ((astereoin.checked + aOpticalout.checked) && 
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter");
DisplayResults.innerHTML = OptoAv;
var AvToOp = ((astereoout.checked + aOpticalin.checked) && 
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/PDIF");
DisplayResults.innerHTML += AvToOp;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It is not clear what you are asking.  Please edit your question, so that we can understand what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you never actually set the HREF as the URL, you are only DISPLAYING in in `innerHTML` and you are appending more than one URL. Instead you need to dynamically create the links.

First I replaced your anchor with a div. Then I added a reusable function for creating links.

**New Code:**

```
        <div id="DisplayResults"></div>

        function create_link(url, target_obj){
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            var linkText = document.createTextNode(url);
            a.appendChild(linkText);
            a.title = url;
            a.href = url;
            target_obj.appendChild(a);
        }

    function Selectport() {

    var aOpticalin = document.getElementById("aOpticalin");
    var aOpticalout = document.getElementById("aOpticalout");
    var astereoout = document.getElementById("astereoout");
    var astereoin = document.getElementById("astereoin");
    var DisplayResults = document.getElementById("DisplayResults");

        if(astereoin.checked && aOpticalout.checked){
           create_link("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter",DisplayResults);
        }

        if(astereoout.checked && aOpticalin.checked){
            create_link("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/PDIF",DisplayResults);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is no problem. If it helped, please upvote and accept it as the answer.

Comment: " one more question  imvain2 how do I display Amazon links in that create_link code

Answer (score 0):

```
//*This is one banner link from Amazon(no spaces), Is it possible to display it in your 
//*code that you did in above
if(astereoin.checked && aOpticalout.checked){
create_link(<iframe style="width:120px;height:240px;" marginwidth="0" 
marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="//ws- 
na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q? 
ServiceVersion=20070822&OneJS=1&Operation=GetAdHtml&MarketPlace=US&source=ac&ref= 
tf_til& ad_type=product_link&tracking_id=whatsmycable- 
20&marketplace=amazon&region=US&placement=B01HGHNCMW&asins=B01HGHNCMW&linkId= 
f3759832fc138a941ade9bde6128b083&show_border=true&link_opens_in_new_window= 
false&price_color=333333&title_color=000000&bg_color=d1d1d1">
</iframe>,DisplayResults);
```

Comment: I added a Amazon link to the code that was created by imvain2. Is it possible to display the link with image etc. with the code he created. please help

Comment: I would suggest accepting my answer and creating a new question as this wasn’t part of your original question .

Comment: It kinda was but I'm new to this.ill put up a new question.exepted and up voted your answer. Thanks again